# Pokemon Api: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-redux, frontend

I'm working with the pokemon API and I'm running into trouble. Here's the original code where I first encountered the problem.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const api = {
  base: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"
}

function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState({});

  const search = evt => {
    if(evt.key === "Enter") {
      fetch (`${api.base}${query}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        setPokemon(result);
        setQuery('');
        console.log(result);
      })
    }
  }

  const weightConverter = weight => {
    return Math.floor(weight / 10) + ".0 kg.";
  }

  const heightConverter = height => {
    return (height / 10) + " m."
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <main>
        <div className="pokedex-search-box">
          <input 
          type="text" 
          className="pokedex-search-bar" 
          placeholder="Search for a Pokémon..."
          onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
          value={query}
          onKeyPress={search}
          ></input>
        </div>
          <div>
            <div className="pokedex">
              <div className="pokedex-left">
                {pokemon.name}
                <br></br>
                {pokemon.id}
              </div>
              <div>
              <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default}></img>
              <br></br>
              {pokemon.types[0].type.name}
              <br></br>
              {pokemon.types[1].type.name}
              <br></br>
              {weightConverter(pokemon.weight)}
              <br></br>
              {heightConverter(pokemon.height)}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Originally this was my code, but after looking up the problem on google I realized that the react dom was loading faster than my api call since you have to input a search that will then fetch the object. Which it can't do that since you have to wait for a search input. After that, I added this little bit to check to see if the object was already called and if not set it to an empty string so that you can use the search.

```
{pokemon.sprites ? (
        <div className="pokedex">
          <div className="pokedex-left">
            {pokemon.name}
            <br></br>
            {pokemon.id}
          </div>
          <div>
          <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default}></img>
          <br></br>
          {pokemon.types[0].type.name}
          <br></br>
          {pokemon.types[1].type.name}
          <br></br>
          {weightConverter(pokemon.weight)}
          <br></br>
          {heightConverter(pokemon.height)}
          </div>
        </div>
        ) : ('')}
```

And that worked fine, but after a few searches I come back to the same problem of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined." I'm new to react so I'm a little lost. I have a temporary solution that works for the first three pokemon and then it breaks after that.

Comment: Looks like `pokemon.types[0]` is undefined :)

Comment: @Dominik I tried to add `pokemon.sprites || pokemon.types` for another check and i still encounter the same error after the 3rd pokemon. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: This isn't a problem with react, instead the issue here is that either pokemon.types[0] or pokemon.types[1] is undefined. Try to console.log(pokemon.types[0], pokemon.types[1]).

Comment: Console log the pokemon object and post it here so we know the shape of your data. (Use `JSON.stringify(pokemon,null,2)`)

Comment: @zigni pokemon.sprites || pokemon.types this check won't work because pokemon.types will be valid as long as there is at least one field inside the types array. Instead, what you need to do is using optional chaining like so: pokemon.types[0]?.type?.name

Comment: @Dominik `VM463:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: pokemon is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:16`

Comment: @Link `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` is what I'm getting as a result. 
Also thank you for that. I didn't know about optional chaining. Definitely going to be using that in the future.

Comment: Replace `console.log(result);` in your `then` call with `console.log(JSON.stringify(result,null,2));` and edit your question to include what the output is

Comment: @Domink I figured it out, some pokemon have two types and other don't and thats the reason it's breaking after the first three. After that they have single types. Thanks for the help guys